# Analysis on manifolds without analysis on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, smooth-manifolds

I wonder if there are any texts that treat analysis on manifolds as a separate topic requiring no knowledge of analysis on $\mathbb{R}^n$

One might say it's a bad idea but i don't see why it shouldn't be an existing alternative when we have the same with linear algebra and algebra nowadays. Math students study abstract theory first, special cases of which they learn when they need them.

Anyway, it is not a discussion of whether it's right or no. I'm only interested in whether such alternatives exist.

Comment: I would guess not. To some extent it is a generalisation of analysis on $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it is hard to avoid. I think a better analogy would be linear algebra and functional analysis. You really can't do the latter without knowing the former.

Comment: You are right that it is generalisation of analysis on $\mathbb{R}^n$. But nowadays students in math sometimes learn generalizations first and special cases later. For example, general topology, abstract algebra(first learn group theory and permutations later, for example) and linear algebra over arbitrary fields(some mathematical students have no need for linear algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ at all). Not to mentition some even learn linear algebra through it's generalization - module theory.

Comment: Seems only fair there should exist at least one such alternative treatment. Or does it?

Comment: I believe it was Steinhaus said that "you must earn the right to generalise" (from "The Scottish Book").

Comment: I guess I don't know how one would characterise a manifold without some appropriate $\mathbb{R}^n$ type structure. But that reflects my biases & limited knowledge.

Comment: I actually took differential geometry at a graduate level before I took multivariable calculus (which I actually never took). I was assigned to grade a calculus 3 course and didn't have access to the textbook, and the only way I knew how to solve the problems was through the differential geometry.

Comment: Spivak's _Calculus on Manifolds_ technically satisfies your requirement; however it does so by first introducing calculus on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then moving to manifolds.

Comment: From a rather different direction, you may be interested into looking at some of the introductory texts on "synthetic differential geometry". But overall it may help if you edit your question to include what exactly you consider "analysis on manifolds".

Answer (score 2):

Try "Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds" by Serge Lang.